Wagtail not saving ParentalManyToManyField
I have a model that looks, simplified like this:
class Partner(ClusterableModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Partnership(Orderable):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    partners = ParentalManyToManyField(
        "partners.Partner",
        related_name="partnerships",
        blank=True,
    )

    panels = [
        FieldPanel("name"),
        FieldPanel("partners", widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple),
    ]

Now on the partnership edit page, the list of checkboxes appear with all the partners in the system, however when changing (checking or unchecking) any of the checkboxes, the changes are not stored after saving.
Changes to a field like name are persisted.
What is the cause of this?

I don't think you're using the right class types here.
Partner looks like it just needs to be a standard Django models.Model. This will give you a master list of partners you can choose from in your partnership.
ClusterableModel is only used when you want to nest models inside other models, ClusterableModel is the parent model type in that case. On the child (orderable) model, you'd set a parental key (many-to-one) back to the ClusterableModel. This is the reverse of what you're needing here.
Depending on your use for Partnership, this should most likely also be models.Model. You would only make this an Orderable if you wanted it to be an inline model (on a page for example) where you wanted to create multiple partnerships, and wanted those partnerships to exist only for that page and to appear in a custom order. This would be multiple partnerships, each with multiple partners, all unique to the parent class instance.
If you don't want a master list of partners and just want to create the partners each time you add a partnership, you could do something like the following:
class Partnership(ClusterableModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    panels = [
        FieldPanel("name"),
        MultiFieldPanel(
            [
                InlinePanel("partnerships"),
            ],
            heading="Partners",
        ),
    ]

class Partner(Orderable):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    partnership = ParentalKey(
        "partners.Partnership",
        related_name="partnerships",
        blank=True,
    )

Partnership is the parent model so is ClusterableModel, partner is the child  so gets the Orderable class. This will allow you to add multiple partners in any order.
EDIT - working example with Partners master list:
from django.db import models
from wagtail.snippets.models import register_snippet
from wagtail.snippets.views.snippets import SnippetViewSet

@register_snippet
class Partner(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Partnership(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    partners = models.ManyToManyField(Partner, related_name='partnerships')

    @property
    def partner_names(self):
        return ', '.join([partner.name for partner in self.partners.all()])

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class PartnershipViewSet(SnippetViewSet):
    model = Partnership
    list_display = ["name", "partner_names"]
    list_filter = {"name": ["icontains"], "partners": ["exact"]}

register_snippet(PartnershipViewSet)



You are right, the ClusterableModel and the Orderable were remainders of an earlier implementation. However I changed both Partner and Partnership to a simple Model now, and upon checking or unchecking anything in the snippet editor, changes are still not saved...

@MaartenUreel I've added a working example using Partner master list and a ManyToManyField on Partnerships. This definitely stores the partners.
